# $C$ is a convex set in $R^n$. For any $x \in \partial{C}$, can we always construct $\{x_n\} \subset R^{n} \setminus cl(C)$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow x$?

Tags: general-topology

I found this statement in a proof of separating hyperplane theorem:

*$C$ is a convex set in $R^n$. For any $x \in \partial{C}$, there exists $\{x_n\} \subset R^{n} \setminus cl(C)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.*

If $C$ is not a convex set, it's easy to find a counter-example that $x$ is on the boundary of $C$, but there is no sequence outside of the closure of $C$ such that $x$ is the limit point of the sequence. If the statement is true, it must be related to the properties of the convex set, which I have no idea how to apply them. May I ask how to prove the statement if it is true?

Comment: You can refer to Rockefeller's  Convex Analysis

Comment: Thanks. I will refer to this book.